# EditText hint does not change when keyboard is in full screen mode?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

My EditText hint does not change when keyboard is in full screen mode. How can I fix this? `Connecting...` is the original hint. The hint does not change when the keyboard is in full screen. !!!

[image]

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final int intervalTime = 10000; // 10 sec
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()  {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
                editText.setHint("new hint"); //set the new hint!

            }
        }, intervalTime);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.me.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Connecting..."
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: where is you  xml

Comment: @NileshRathod I'm gonna put it now

Comment: didn't get you question

Comment: @NileshRathod Can't you see that the edittext hint is "new hint" but when I open the full screen keyboard it's "connecting..." ??

Comment: @NileshRathod Isn't that a problem???

Comment: why would anyone downvote this?

Comment: it's a simple question!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
    myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus)
            myEditText.setHint("new hint");
        else
            myEditText.setHint("");
    }
});
```

Comment: this is not what I want. 
Can you see that the EditText hint is "new hint" but when I open the full screen keyboard it's "connecting..." ? Yes or no?

Comment: but in xml you set hint as    android:hint="Connecting..."

Comment: The hint does not change when the keyboard is in full screen.

Comment: do you understand??

Comment: i think may be it beacuse of handler

Comment: @Downvoters pls. explain exactly what's wrong with this answer so that I can address?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `hint` in `xml` as `android:hint="write your hint here"`.

Comment: I set it as `android:hint="Connecting".` as you can see.

Comment: your hint will not disappear in opening of keyboard , it will disappear when you start writing a words

Comment: Who said I wanted it to disappear??

Comment: can you elaborate your question??

Comment: Can you see that the EditText hint is "new hint" but when I open the full screen keyboard it's "connecting..." ? Yes or no?

Comment: can't you see that this is not normal?

Comment: The hint does not change when the keyboard is in full screen.